# Error : 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Why I keep getting this error in one of my Jupyter Notebook

```
!cat ../data/filename.csv
```

Error:

```
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

anyone, please help.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
!more ../data/filename.csv
```

Or

```
!type ../data/filename.csv
```

Comment: @RohanMitra Those are windows commands. "cat" isn't a windows command hence your original error.  'more' and 'type' are windows commands for displaying the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has "type" function where as Ubuntu has "cat" function.
for windows

Try:

!type filename

for Ubuntu

Try:

!cat filename

Answer (score 0):

Install '[Cygwin][1]' to add Linux command in the window. download from this link https://www.cygwin.com.

Answer (score 0):

for windows Jupyter notebook:

```
!type ..\data\filename.csv
```