# Jupyter notebook is not able to execute unix command (i.e. ls,pwd etc)?

Tags: python, jupyter

I wrote `!cat array.txt` , and the result was:

> ERROR: 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: The error message suggests you're running on Windows. `cat` is a Unix command.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge , it doesn't matter with jupyter it works fine in both windows and linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159645/error-cat-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`%cat array.txt`